# I'm trying to convert MySQLi code to PDO code, but no success

Tags: php, function, mysqli, pdo, multi-level

I have working code with MySQLi, but I am making some new project and want to do with PDO, that shows multi-level category view. I'm new with PDO and still learning.

This is my working MySQLi:

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
    global $db;
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ORDER BY name ASC");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
            echo '<tr><td>'.$sub_mark.''.$row['name'].'</td><td><button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>';
            categoryTree($row['id'], $sub_mark.'---');
        }
    }
}
```

Closed variant to PDO what I achieve but now working:

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){

    $query = "SELECT * FROM ws_categories WHERE parent_id = $parent_id ORDER BY name ASC";
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
            echo '<tr><td>'.$sub_mark.''.$row['name'].'</td><td><button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>';
            categoryTree($row['id'], $sub_mark.'---');
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in

p.s. I have included config.php with pdo db connection that connect properly.

Please help me, I try several ways but no success.

Sorry for my English :)

Comment: `$connection` is not defined in the scope of `categoryTree`. Either pass it in or make it a global as you did originally.

Comment: OP, Did you later add the `Error: Fatal Error:` part? When I initially checked it wasn't in the text.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to iterate over the wrong result set. And I am unsure if the attribute `num_rows` is set in a fetchAll.

You can replace the `if` and `while` part with a single `while`/`foreach`.
If you want to use the [fetchAll](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) function you can simply `foreach` loop over the result set. However, if you do a big query this can take a lot of memory so it is not always preferred to do so.

For the fetchAll solution you would end up with the following:

```
$results = $query->fetchAll()
foreach ($results as $result) {
    var_dump($result); // Process data here.
}
```

If you want to use the [fetch](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) function which is more memory/resource friendly you can use a while loop like you used in MySQLi:

```
while ($data = $query->fetch()) {
    var_dump($data); // Process data here.
}
```

edit:

I just noticed you are directly inserting variables into a query, this is bad practice as it allows for sql-injection. If you are using PDO anyway take a look at [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) you can replace the variable with a placeholder eg. `:parent_id` then on your execute call you pass an array which contains the value of the parent_id and it does some sql injection prevention.

That would look like:

```php
$query = 'select * from ws_categories where parent_id = :parent_id';
$statement = $connection->prepare($query);
$statement->execute(['parent_id' => $parent_id]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this code work, but show only parent categories without subcategories:

```
function categoryTree($parent_id = 0, $sub_mark = ''){
    global $connection;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM ws_categories WHERE parent_id = :parent_id';
    $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
    $statement->execute(['parent_id' => $parent_id]);

        while ($row = $statement->fetch()) {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$sub_mark.''.$row['name'].'</td><td><button type="button" name="update" id="'.$row["id"].'" class="btn btn-info btn-sm update"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td></tr>';
                categoryTree($row['id'], $sub_mark.'---');

    }
}
```